# double object memory leak?

Tags: c#, java, android, memory-leaks

here's the setup for c# program:

Inside Main class: `ObjA MyObjA = new ObjA();`

Inside ObjA: `ObjB MyObjB = new ObjB();`

So main has a reference to ObjA, and ObjA has a reference to ObjB.

Now let's say in the main class, i set `MyObjA = null;` Will the garbage collector come along and destroy ObjA? Or will it save it since it has a reference to ObjB (which is not destroyed yet)?

You can see how this would be a huge memory leak in the latter case. But as a side note, if the former case is true, then would it take 1 pass or 2 passes of the GC before ObjB is destroyed?

Also, could someone tell me what would happen in Android Java too? Those are the two languages I'm working with atm.

Comment: You can't set `ObjA = null`. You can only set the pointer to ObjA to point to null instead: `MyObjA = null`.

Comment: Android and / or Java have not even a problem with circular references since garbage collection is not based on simple reference counting (e.g. count how many objects have a reference to me, free memory once count is 0) like it is (was?) in [ObjectiveC](http://pivotallabs.com/why-not-to-use-arc/).

Comment: @KeithPayne thanx, was a typo/mentalo, i edited it to what i meant

Comment: @zapl ok, well how does the GC determine who to destroy then? BTW my example wasnt circular reference either. It was really a chain of references, and I'm asking if you set one link to null, does everything else down the chain get destroyed (and in 1 GC pass or multiple passes)?

Comment: I don't know how it works in detail (and there are at least 3 or 4 different GC algorithms you can configure for the Oracle JVM) but GC starts at "GC roots" (AFAIK the system class loader that references system classes, which then reference other objects) and traverses the hierarchy until everything reachable from there is marked as "referenced" and anything else can be removed (if removal does not recreate references in `finalize`). The algorithm might be slightly different on Android but it uses the same schema.  http://www.infoq.com/articles/G1-One-Garbage-Collector-To-Rule-Them-All

Answer (score 1):

Both MyObjA and MyObjB will be destroyed since they're unreachable from any GC roots (things like static variables, stack variables, or things that are recursively pointed to by things like this).

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by two passes. The details of the Java garbage collector are somewhat complicated but, if the objects are unreachable they should be cleaned up in a single GC cycle.

Comment: 2 passes, as in first ObjA gets destroyed, and then on the next pass it realizes nothing is pointing to ObjB, so it gets destroyed the 2nd time around ... also, how did i get edit access to your post!?

Comment: @user1705043: In a simple mark and sweep what would happen is that the GC would traverse from the GC roots, marking everything it sees as reachable. Then it would notice that MyObjA and MyObjB weren't reached and clean them up. So a single run of the garbage collector.

Comment: @user1705043: I think you just made an edit suggestion. Looks like you need 2000 points to flat out edit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit.

Comment: that's really odd cuz when i clicked edit, i got the whole box with all your writing; i cud have erased it all but had no reason to flame or be malacious, unlike some other forums i know......btw, that edit button is still there under ur post, so if ur as curious as me then let me kno so i can try to erase ur post lol